# Push constant directly or Mov Eax and Push Eax

Tags: assembly, x86

There are a difference in push a constant value directly for call a function, instead of mov the value to eax and push eax.

For example for do this in C:
GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

many compilers generate this:

```
;B8 F5 FF FF FF
MOV EAX,-11

;50
PUSH EAX

CALL GetStdHandle
```

and manually I'm using;

```
;6A F5
PUSH -11

CALL GetStdHandle
```

There are wrong pushing the value directly instead load it on eax and push eax ?

Comment: No. What you are doing is just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should be ok, assuming the code is in 32 bit mode.

You could explicitly specify a 32 bit immediate, but in the case of Visual Studio (2005) assembler (ML.EXE), it used the full 32 bit operand size instead of a sign extended byte value:

```
; 68 F5 FF FF FF
;
        push    dword ptr -11
```

Even specifying a byte ptr with Visual Studio's assembler (ML.EXE) works:

```
; 6A F5
;
        push    byte ptr -11
```

However, using a word ptr results in a 66 prefix and a 16 bit push (ESP subtracted by 2 instead of 4):

```
; 66 68 F5 FF
;
        push    word ptr -11
```

In this case the 66 prefix changes the operand size (the value pushed onto the stack) to 16 bits.

Comment: From Intel's manual: _"If the source operand is an immediate and its size is less than the operand size, a sign-extended value is pushed on the stack."_. So in practice he's still placing a 32-bit value on the stack (assuming the OP is building a 32-bit executable).

Comment: `dword ptr` really just overrides the width of the immediate, rather than treating it as a memory operand at that absolute address?  MASM is insane. (In NASM, you'd use `push strict dword -11` for the immediate, `push [-11]` for memory.)  Hmm, GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` is MASM-like, and also treats it as push-immediate (but ignores the dword specifier and uses a byte immediate)